# How to compute only URL in grails (without <a> tag)?

Tags: java, grails, web-applications, gsp, grails-3.0

If I write

```
<g:link controller="book" action="list">Book List</g:link>
```

in GSP it will render to something like

```
<a href="/book/list">Book List</a>
```

in HTML.

But what if I wish to call this URL with AJAX? I don't need `<a>` tag anymore, I need only url `/book/list`.

How to compute it?

Note that it should depends on application context, trailing slash etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use createLink instead, here is the [doc](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html)

Some examples:

```
 // generates "/shop/book/show/1"
<g:createLink action="show" id="1" />
// generates "/shop/book/show?foo=bar&boo=far"
<g:createLink action="show" params="[foo: 'bar', boo: 'far']"/>

// generates "/shop/book"
<g:createLink controller="book" />

// generates "/shop/book/list"
<g:createLink controller="book" action="list" />

// generates "/shop/book/list"
<g:createLink url="[action:'list',controller:'book']" />
```